# Java 8 lambda String.Split to map error

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a list of strings, split them by a character into a map, then parse the input as int.

Basically from "106S2" i would get a map of ints {106, 2}.

The problem is that:

1. s.split("S")[0]; // here i get error "cannot resolve split"
2. The second lambda does not throw any error, but if i rewrite it as `s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("S")[1])` gives me an error again.

I don't think i am doing anything wrong, the short form should work, but both in intellij and eclipse i get errors.

```
    Map<String, Integer> c02 = Arrays.asList(
  "103S2", "106S2", "109S2", "112S2", "115S2", "118S2", "121S2", "124S2", "127S2", "130S2", "133S2", "136S2")
  .stream()
  .collect(
    Collectors.toMap(s -> {
      return s.split("S")[0]; // here i get error "cannot resolve split"
    }, s -> {
      String s1 = s.split("S")[1];
      return Integer.parseInt(s1);
    }));
System.out.println(c02);
```

Comment: I didn't receive any errors at all when running this exact code.

Comment: @SamOrozco, you will get the same error if you change the type of c02 map from `Map<String, Integer> c02` to let's say `Map<String, String> c02` or `Map<String, Double> c02`. I think, this what was happening.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? I cannot replicate your error. And to be honest do not understand how to generate  "cannot resolve split" error. If `split()` cannot split it returns an empty array. Then when you try to get an array value the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown...

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc if I change the Map type I get a compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

The result should be declared as `Map<String, Integer>`.

So it should look like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> c02 = 
        Arrays.asList("103S2", "106S2", "109S2", "112S2", 
        "115S2", "118S2", "121S2", "124S2",
        "127S2", "130S2", "133S2", "136S2")
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.split("S")[0], s -> {
            String s1 = s.split("S")[1];
            return Integer.valueOf(s1);
        }));
```

But your pipeline can be made simpler (avoiding extraneous `split` call):

```
Map<String, Integer> c02 = 
        Arrays.asList("103S2", "106S2", "109S2", "112S2", 
                "115S2", "118S2", "121S2", "124S2",
                "127S2", "130S2", "133S2", "136S2")
        .stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("S"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], 
                s -> Integer.valueOf(s[1])));
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any future code duplication some pieces of code like `s.split("S")[1]`, I would recommend creating a separate entity to store the pair:

```
    class Pair {
        private final int k;
        private final int v;

        Pair(String raw) {
            this(raw.split("S"));
        }

        Pair(String[] raw) {
            this(raw[0], raw[1]);
        }

        Pair(String k, String v) {
            this(Integer.parseInt(k), Integer.parseInt(v));
        }

        Pair(int k, int v) {
            this.k = k;
            this.v = v;
        }

        public int getK() {
            return this.k;
        }

        public int getV() {
            return this.v;
        }
    }
```

That is a more functional way, but dramatically clearer and more maintainable.
And the final code will look this.

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> collect = Stream.of(
            "103S2", "106S2", "109S2", "112S2", "115S2", "118S2", "121S2", "124S2", "127S2", "130S2", "133S2", "136S2")
            .map(Pair::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getK, Pair::getV));
    System.out.println(collect);
```

And now, your code clearer and completely decoupled.
And one more benefit, method reference will be inlined by JIT and will run faster.

Comment: see  @ernest_k 's  second example below, i can just do `.map(s -> s.split("S"))` which looks much better and simpler than a new class.

Comment: @TheBestPessimist: I saw it, but there are a lot of "depends on", so, i provided my solution and explained why. That is *one of the ways* to make your code maintainable and easier to grow. This is not "how-to".